# Production SharePoint 2013 Drive and space allocations

Tags: 2013, hardware

I'm setting up SP 2013 with 2 App servers and 2 WFE servers. I'm allocating 100GB for the system drive on each box since they always fill up so quickly! But I'd like to get your thoughts/experience on the number and types of drives as well as how you sized them for the APP and the WFE roles. I realize these are based on requirements, current data sizes, etc. but I've not been able to get anything out of my current company.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to think before make a selection of Drive Space.

1. Try minimum thing son system drive, move the sharepoint installation location.
2. You should have a separate Drive for the Logs File( IIS logs & ULS Logs), Logs fill the drive space quickly. So move logs on different drive.
3. You should have another drive for the putting for all installation files and other scripts etc. I called it temp drive, where i put all the files which i will gona use for short time, i.e if i want to take a backup of site collection then keep that bak file on this drive.

Comment: Thanks Waqas! ow much space do you allocate for these different drives?

Comment: i have 120GB for the Logs and 60GB for temp files and 80GB for system drive....this is for production.